# ERROR at line 1: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

On this I am getting an error

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.

Can someone help me on this I am not familiar on `sql`.

```
select cerps_accnt_code, cost_centre, SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_DUE) 
from globe_billing_report where tag like '%Duncan%'
```

Comment: Check these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+not+a+single-group+group+function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Group by` while using aggregate functions in `sql`

```
select cerps_accnt_code, cost_centre, SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_DUE) 
from globe_billing_report 
where tag like '%Duncan%'
group by cerps_accnt_code, cost_centre
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `group by` clause as below

```
select cerps_accnt_code, cost_centre, SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_DUE) 
from globe_billing_report 
where tag like '%Duncan%'
group by cerps_accnt_code, cost_centre
```

Comment: @alkatraz I'm glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer to close the question.